# SQL Query to create a column to determine count from historical data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given: columns "basket" & "Fruit".
Output: Column "Count present in all the previous basket"

How to check if a fruit in a basket is present in all the preceding baskets and get the total count present?

For ex: Basket 2 contains Berry, Banana and Orange, now i need to check basket 1 to determine the count of these fruits. In the same way, for the fruits in basket 3, basket 1 and basket 2 are checked.

How can i do this using an SQL query? Currently i'm doing this on the application side using loops, rowfilter etc which consumes a lot of times as i've more than million rows.

[image]

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got 2 product specific answers.)

Comment: @jarlh using Microsoft SQL Server. Trying out the answers to reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also go with a window function I think. I am subtracting 1 to avoid the first count for each fruit. Maybe someone can provide a more elegant solution.

```
select *, 
       (count(*) over (partition by fruit order by basket) - 1) 
from t 
order by basket, fruit;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could argue that `rank()` is more natural?

Comment: Good answer. If `fruit, basket` combination has duplicates then you must use `rows unbounded preceding` in the `over`. It's also faster. Also instead of `- 1` you could use `rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding` but I believe that is slower than `- 1`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the feedback. I am not sure if -1 would work in all edge cases.

Comment: @shawnt00 How would you go with rank()?

Comment: As for questions of elegance they do the same thing: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5f2db3af400b1146d213383f827a45c

Comment: @romborimba Thanks. If a basket contains a duplicate, say 2 apples in basket 1, then the count should show 0 for both apples in basket 1 as i'm only trying to compare against all the previous baskets. In the link below, the apples in basket 1 should show 0 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22ce99d7cfba14d9fbb6e342c5c3e4d8

Comment: @KannanRajan The most straightforward way to tackle duplicates is using a distinct subquery: `select *, 
(count(*) over (partition by fruit order by basket) - 1)
from (select distinct basket, fruit from t) a 
order by basket, fruit;`

Comment: @KannanRajan If you also want to show all the lines (because the distinct will remove some) you can also do something like this:
`with counts as(
select a.basket, a.fruit, count(*) over (partition by a.fruit order by a.basket) - 1 as total
from (select distinct t.basket, t.fruit from t) a
)
select counts.fruit, counts.basket, counts.total from counts join t on counts.basket = t.basket and counts.fruit = t.fruit
order by counts.basket, counts.fruit;`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need a simple correlated subquery, such as:

```
select *, (
  select Count(*) from t t2 
  where t2.basket < t.basket 
    and t2.fruit = t.fruit
) "Count in prev baskets"
from t;
```